# ruby - http client which support both async requests and SSL support without cert verification

Tags: ruby, ssl, httpclient

i am looking for an http client who support both

1. SSL support with verifaction VERIFY_NONE :  `http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`
2. async calls

what I already covered is a couple of libraries :

```
net/https
```

which support SSL VERIFY_NONE but has no async mechanism

```
manticore
```

which support async mechanism but [failed to support SSL VERIFY_NONE](https://github.com/cheald/manticore/issues/53)

```
Unirest
```

I failed to find any documentation regarding my 2 requirements

Can anyone please advise me on a rest client which does both?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eventmachine gem` to make http calls asyn. Please take a look at: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine